# Setting up our new Dev server What is the easiest way to assign multiple IP addresses

Tags: windows, installation

I'm setting up our new Dev server, what is the easiest way to assign multiple IP addresses to Windows 2008 Server Network Adapter?

I'm setting up our development machine, running IIS 7 and want to have the range between 192.168.1.200 - .254 available when I'm setting up a new website in IIS 7.

Comment: You want to do this programmatically ... right?

Comment: either script or manual. just looking to push 192.168.1.200 through 254 to the network adapter so it will be available to IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete CMD.EXE loop:

```
FOR /L %b IN (200,1,254) DO netsh interface ip add address "your_adapter" 192.168.1.%b 255.255.255.0
```

In the code above, replace "your_adapter" with the actual interface name (usually "Local Area Connection"). In addition, the netmask at the end is an assumption of /24 or Class C subnet; substitute the correct netmask.

Answer (score 2):

```
> netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.201 255.255.255.0
```

Wrap in a cmd.exe "for" loop to add multiple IPs.

EDIT: (from Brian) "Local Area Connection" above is a placeholder, make sure you use the actual network adapter name on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Network Connections -> Local Area Network Connection Properties -> TCP/IP Properties -> Advanced -> IP Settings -> Add Button.

Comment: that IS a way. but it is a very slow and manual process. I'm looking for something better.

Comment: The title of the question asks: "what is the easiest…”, and in the question body a total of 55 extra addresses is requested to be entered. Your suggestion does not fit :(